# FOSRest is not handling OptimisticLockException

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, fosrestbundle

With this configuration, ... I expected to handle the request and return 409 code instead of 500.

```
fos_rest:
    body_listener: true
    routing_loader:
        default_format: json
    exception:
        enabled: true
        codes:
            'Doctrine\ORM\OptimisticLockException': 409
        messages:
            'Doctrine\ORM\OptimisticLockException': true
```

> [2017-09-26 12:59:48] app.CRITICAL: The optimistic lock on an entity failed. errors: array ( ) {"exception":"[object] (Doctrine\ORM\OptimisticLockException(code: 0): The optimistic lock on an entity failed. at /home/vagrant/project-api/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/OptimisticLockException.php:64)"} []

Comment: try here, does that help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27681215/optimistic-locking-fails-because-doctrine-cannot-determine-version

Comment: Mine is fos_rest configuration problem.